# all() function not returning expected value in Python

Tags: python-3.x

In Python,

```py
a=[not(0)+1] 
print(all(a))
```

This returns False. But shouldn't it be True? Since, `a=[2]`, and all integer values other than 0 are considered True. Thus, `all()` should return True right?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `all` - your question should be, why is `not(0) + 1` false? You claim that `a = [2]` but if it were then you wouldn't have had to write `not(0) + 1` to produce the issue.

Comment: Fair enough. How is not(0)+1 =False? Shouldn't it be True?

Comment: The brackets are misleading; `not` is an operator, not a function, and has lower precedence than `+`, so you are effectively doing `not ((0) + 1)`.

Comment: Ah. Now I understand! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `all()` should return True if all the values in a list are true. In your case if you do

```py
a = [2]
print(all(a))
```

this will return true.
But when you are doing

```py
a = [not(0) +1]
```

your list of a is becoming
`a = [False]` as `not(0) + 1` returns False.

```py
a = [2]
a = [not(0) + 1]
print(a)
# a = [False]
print(all(a))
# False
```

Hence, this prints result as False

Comment: `not 0` == True (1)    *Always!

Comment: Allright. But I still do not understand how not(0)+1 returns False. I always thought not(0)=1, so (1+1)=2=True. What's wrong in this logic?

Comment: think of it as `not 0 + 1` I guess that will answer your question